# How to safely store an id object in a C++ void* member under ARC when no other references hold on to the object?

Tags: objective-c, casting, automatic-ref-counting, void-pointers

I'm working with Box2D (C++) and I create an Objective-C object and assign it to a Box2D body's `userData` property, which is of type `void*`.

Now in some cases the `void* userData` may be the only active reference to that ObjC object. Therefore, because I used `(__bridge void*)` in the assignment, ARC is letting it go. That's something I need to fix.

I've been pondering the options to prevent this from happening? I read [Clang's ARC documentation](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#arc-objects-restrictions-conversion), specifically the parts about bridge casting (as well as Q&A on SO) as well as nodding to the various bridge casting constructs they consider to be "ill-formed".

Still, my first thought was to use `(__bridge_retained void*)` in the initial assignment to userData. But that made me wonder how to balance that retain? I obviously can't send release to the object.

So would I have to `CFRelease()` the object? Or would it need to be `CFBridgingRelease()`? Or are both illegal here?

Is a `(__bridge_transfer void*)` cast from `userData` to a temporary id type enough, perhaps while setting userData to NULL afterwards? Is that even a good idea?

I know the alternative would be to keep a separate `NSArray`/`NSDictionary` for the `userData` objects and keep them in synch with the lifetime of the Box2D body, adding and removing them in synch with their Box2D bodies.

But this feels like overkill because here I know what I'm doing, I know I need to `+1` the object for as long as the Box2D body is active, and `-1` the object when the Box2D body is removed. Plus I know that there are only two methods where the Box2D bodies are being added and removed, and direct access to `userData` is not even possible in my framework because all Box2D objects are hidden behind Objective-C interfaces/wrappers.

Setting possibly "ill-formed" aside for a moment, what would you recommend I should do in this situation?

Comment: @Emil: thanks for fixing the inline code, I was just about to do it myself.

Comment: No problem, I must admit it was weird to be editing such a trivial thing in a 20k-user's post! Ha :D

Comment: yeah sometimes I ask really stoopid questions :)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`__bridge_retained` means "Send this ARC object off into no-ARC land by retaining it". You call this when you need to create an "untracked" `void *`. So, in your case, `userData = (__bridge_retained void *)obj`.

`__bridge_transfer` means "Pull this object back from no-ARC land by releasing it". You call this when you want to effectively invalidate the `void *`. So, `obj = (__bridge_transfer id)userData`. After this, the `userData` pointer is not safe to use; instead, you work only with `obj`. When `obj` goes out of scope, ARC will release it for the last time. This may entail creating a temporary `id` solely for this purpose.

So, in your case, you do want to use `__bridge_retained` when you ship the object off into Box2D, and use `__bridge_transfer` when you want to invalidate the `userData`. If you need to access the `userData` as an Objective-C object but not invalidate the pointer, use plain `__bridge`.

Comment: Good. I was mainly confused about casting it back because it doesn't seem to "do anything" to the object, when in fact it does. Style-wise I think I'll prefer: CFBridgingRelease(body->GetUserData()) followed by body->SetUserData(NULL). From what I understand that's the same thing as __bridge_transfer cast.

Comment: I would actually use `__bridge_*` myself, because this doesn't really concern CF in any way.

Comment: Hmmm … yes, but then I need to assign to a local var, and then also do something with that var (set it to nil) so the compiler doesn't complain about the unused var.

Comment: Interesting, CFBridgingRelease simply does a __bridge_transfer, it's just a macro declared as: NS_INLINE id CFBridgingRelease(CFTypeRef CF_CONSUMED X) {
    return (__bridge_transfer id)X;
}  (just without the compiler complaining about the unused result if I ignore the return value)

Answer (score 2):

You misunderstood what the author of the documentation was meaning for "ill-formed". This is ill-formed:

```
NSData* data; // Initialized
NSData* data2= (__bridge NSData*) data;
```

Also this is ill-formed:

```
void* data; // Initialized
void* data2= (__bridge void*) data;
```

This is not ill-formed:

```
NSData* data; // Initialized
void* data2= (__bridge void*) data;
```

To be not ill-formed is enough that the left value is retainable and the right value is not retainable, or viceversa. So since in your case your're casting object pointers to raw pointers and viceversa, your approach is correct.

At your place I'd implements a smart pointer that sends a CFBridgingRetain message on construction, and a CFBridgingRelease message on destruction.